# roscpp - Convert uint8[] into a known struct

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I've got a universal message type for all kinds of data that comes in through a UDP socket. This message just contains a fixed size array of uint8[16].

What I would like to do is to convert the uint8 array into a pre-defined `struct`. I know what the struct has to look like so if I just had a usual C array of chars I'd just do a cast. But IIRC that doesn't work with a uint8[] since it is a more complex type of array.

So how do I do that? How do I kind of unmarshall that uint8 array into a struct?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72469/roscpp---convert-uint8%5B%5D-into-a-known-struct/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it working. It's really just as simple as

```
typedef struct {
  char a;
  float b;
  char c;
} stc;
```

And later...

```
stc* d = (stc*)&msg.data;
```

Since the other side of the line does packing and converting endianness I had to take care of having all the uint8 in the right place before doing this.

It's working. Thanks anyway!

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0